# calculating quantiles of certain divisions

Tags: statistics

Is there any formula or other way to calculate:

1. The $p$ quantile of $X\sim\exp(1)$ (or generally $x~\exp(λ)$)
2. The $p$ quantile of $X\sim\text{uni}[a,b]$

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The quantile function is the inverse of the cumulative distribution function. So compute the cdf $F$ in each case, then the $p$ quantile is given by $F^{-1}(p)$.